# Sending and receiving

Tags: c, pointers

I have a task where I have to create multiple queues. Currently I am stuck as I do not understand how I would be able to send a message to a specific queue as well as how to send/receive the inputted message to that specific queue. This is the code I have written:

```
typedef struct _node {
    const char *message;
    struct _node *next;
} node_t;
```

Comment: You shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: Which line are you talking about please?

Comment: `(struct _node*)malloc(sizeof(struct _node));`, for example. Also, you don't need to cast the return of a function as you do here: `msg_queues = (msg_queue_t *) (MsgQs_t *) createQ();`

Comment: Also, how are we supposed to know which queue to send/receive the message to/from? `msg_queues` is an array of queues, so what is the expected behavior?

Comment: ok, edited the code to not cast malloc

Comment: That is my problem @SaucyGoat as i do not understand how to do that

Comment: Well if you can't tell us what you're trying to do, I don't think we can help. If that is an assignment, either ask your teacher for help or read the problem statement more carefully.

Comment: Basically i need to create multiple queues having some sort of id, where messages have to be sent to a particular queue that was created. Then, a message can be received from a particular queue that was chosen. My problem is that i do not know how to go about this part to send and receive messages to a particular queue. Each method has a comment above it with some explanation also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204672/discussion-between-saucy-goat-and-nathan-camilleri).

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code produces the expected behavior:

```
typedef struct msg_queue_node {
    char * message;
    struct msg_queue_node * next;
} msg_queue_node_t;


typedef struct msg_queue {
    msg_queue_node_t * head, * tail;
} msg_queue_t;


int main(void)
{
    int i, id;      // indentifies the message queue in the array
    msg_queue_t * msg_queues = malloc(NUM_QUEUES * sizeof(msg_queue_t*));

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_QUEUES; i++)
        msg_queues[i] = createQ();

    // ...

    while ( /*condition*/ ) {

        scanf("%c %d", choice, id);

        switch (choice) {
            case '4':
                printf("\nSending a message\nEnter message to send:");
                scanf("%s", msg);
                sendMessage(msg_queues[id-1], msg);
                break;
            case '5':
                printf("\nReceiving a message\n");
                printf("Message received: %s\n", receiveMessage(msg_queues[id-1]));
                break; 
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Where `msg_queues` is an array with size `NUM_QUEUES`.

In my solution, we expect the user to input the identifier of the queue that he wishes to send/receive a message to/from. I assumed that the identifier for each queue corresponded to its index in the array + 1, i.e. the identifiers are 1, ..., NUM_QUEUES.

Comment: Need an explanation here. Posting only code isn't enough.

Comment: @nicomp Done. I had completely forgot to post the explanation, thank you for reminding me!